# How the pattern emerging in the exponents of the terms of a binomial expansion is proven?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Every article I've read just shows that the exponents of a term in the expansion are of the form $$a^{n-k}b^{k}$$ but how to prove that this is really true?

Comment: You can probably use mathematical induction if you know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the principle of [mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) we can sketch a proof like this:

1. Base case: n=1, $$(a+b)^1 = a^1+b^1 = a^1b^0 + a^0b^1$$
2. Assume true for case $n$: $$(a+b)^n = a^n + c_1 a^{n-1}b^1 + \cdots+ b^n$$
3. Induction step : investigate case $n+1$: $$(a+b)^{n+1} = (a+b)(a+b)^n = distribute =  a^1b^0(a+b)^n +b^1a^0(a+b)^n$$

We see that step 3 will add 1 separately to each of the previously $a$ and $ b$ exponents and by induction we have our result like a domino game,

1. Since it is true for $n=1$ it must be true for $n+1=2$.
2. Since it is true for $n=2$ it must be true for $n+1=3$
3. And so on...

Comment: This was a life-saving answer. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You multiply $n$ times $(a+b)$.

What things would you obtain?

By the rule of multiplying sums, any term of the product is obtained by taking either $a$ or $b$ from each bracket. Since there are $n$ brackets, you have to make $n$ choices. If you had chosen "$b$" $k$ times, you have $n-k$ times $a$ chosen.

Hence every term of the product is of the form $a^{n-k}b^k$ for some $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: What is that rule which says that any term of the expansion is obtained by taking either $a$ or $b$ from each bracket? I've never heard of this before. May you please provide a reference? Thank you.

Comment: it is just the identity: $(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)=a_1a_2+a_1b_2+b_1a_2+b_1b_2$, look at the form of terms on the right side (the first one is taken from first bracket, the second one from the second...)

Comment: You want to say that I take the first term in the first bracket and multiply that number with the two in the second bracket and then take the second term of the second bracket and multiply that with the first and second term of the first bracket right? And it's the same if I start with the second term of the first bracket and follow similarly. But how this generalizes to multiple brackets? Thanks a lot.